# Error when extracting rotation from Eigen::Isometry3d?

Tags: c++, eigen

```
Eigen::Isometry3d M = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
cout << M.rotation <<endl;
```

When I typed the `'.'` after `M`, the `'rotation'` popped out in the list, compiled the file and run, come to the error:

```
invalid use of non-static member function...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a member function and hence you need to call it. 
Try

```
std::cout << M.rotation() << std::endl;
//                     ^^
```

This has been defined in the header *Transform.h*; goto its definition for further details.